# Django filter many to many field in admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have three objects:

```
Thing
  some fields

Bucket
  things = models.ManyToManyField(Thing)

User
  buckets = models.ManyToManyField(Bucket)
  things = models.ManyToManyField(Thing)
```

When editing my "Bucket" field in the admin, I want to be able to select Things, but only those things that are in the "Things" list on the user currently logged in.

How can I do that? In  other words, how can I filter the list of Things in the Bucket admin?

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 49):

There is a [formfield_for_manytomany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany). Usage is similar to the answer given by defuz.

> ```
> ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)¶
> ```
>
> Like the `formfield_for_foreignkey` method, the `formfield_for_manytomany` method can be overridden to change the
>   default formfield for a many to many field. For example, if an owner
>   can own multiple cars and cars can belong to multiple owners – a many
>   to many relationship – you could filter the Car foreign key field to
>   only display the cars owned by the User:
>
> ```
> class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>     def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
>         if db_field.name == "cars":
>             kwargs["queryset"] = Car.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
>         return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
> ```

Comment: Note that `super()` requires arguments: `return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)`

Comment: @Travis `super()` doesn't require arguments in python3.

Answer (score 31):

Read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey):

```
class BucketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "things":
             kwargs["queryset"] = Things.objects.filter(...)
        return super(BucketAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Note that `formfield_for_foreignkey` is used for ForeignKey, and `formfield_for_manytomany` for ManyToManyField.

Comment: Also note that in python3 you can use `super()` instead of `super(BucketAdmin, self)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with [django-selectable](http://django-selectable.readthedocs.org/en/version-0.5.2/advanced.html#chained-selection) or [django-autocomplete-light](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dependant.html).