# How to filter the class to which the model is related in a ManyToManyField relation in Django?

Tags: django

I would like to filter the class `Location` to which the model `House` is related. The idea is to limit the choices of `Location` based on the value of the field `country` in the admin pannel. Is it something possible and if so, how can I do that?

```
class House(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name='country'
                                 )
    city = models.ManyToManyField(
        Location,
        related_name='city'
    )
```

Basically I would like someting like that but Django throw an error saying `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet`.

```
city = models.ManyToManyField(
    Location.objects.filter(country=country,
    related_name='city'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class HouseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "city":
             kwargs["queryset"] = Location.objects.filter(country=country)
        return super(HouseAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

The source [Django filter many to many field in admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170267/django-filter-many-to-many-field-in-admin)

Comment: Thanks you definitely pointed me to the right direction! unfortunnatly I'm unable to filter `Location` models based on the selected `country`

Comment: Shall I create a new class in `admin.py` of shall I add the method under `class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):` ? the problem is that `country` is unknow here

Comment: When using `kwargs["queryset"] = Location.objects.filter(exchange=request.country)` it says `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'country'
`

Comment: i found a better solution, you can use django_smart_selects.

Comment: it will do the exactly what you want.