# Filtering ManyToMany Field in Django not working as expected

Tags: python, django

I'm using the Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany) as well as some previous StackOverflow questions to figure this out but I can't seem to get it working. My goal is to be able to filter models based on a ManyToManyField. I followed the Mozilla Django tutorial to get this far but it didn't filter by ManyToManyField (in my case, category), so I wanted to add that.

models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter a category')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class BakingPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    ingredients = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    instructions = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, help_text='Select a category')

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def display_category(self):
        return ', '.join(category.name for category in self.category.all())

    display_category.short_description = "Category"
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import BakingPost, Category

# admin.site.register(BakingPost)
# admin.site.register(Category)


@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


@admin.register(BakingPost)
class BakingPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'author', 'created_date', 'published_date', 'display_category')
    list_filter = ('created_date', 'published_date')  # i want to be able to filter by category here too

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "category":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Category.objects.filter(name=request.user)
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Without formfield_for_manytomany right above, editing a BakingPost in the admin section of Django works fine.
[image: As expected]

When I implement those 4 lines, all my values for the Category field disappear when trying to edit a BakingPost and it doesn't even give me a filter box.
[image: Here's what I mean]
[image: No filter box]

Comment: It looks odd, unless you have a `Category` that has the same name as the username of the user, this will not work. Your `Category` has no "owner" field so you can not filter on who "owns" the category.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I figured the "owner" in the Django docs was a variable they created in the "Car" model. I tried putting "owner" when I copied the example but it threw errors saying to use "name" or some other value I forgot already.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Oh. Well that was easy. Lol great thanks for the help. If you want to add it as an answer I'll be happy to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern you may be trying to follow (eg [Django filter many to many field in admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170267/django-filter-many-to-many-field-in-admin)) is for trying to limit what choices of category are valid to assign in the admin when editing a `BakingPost`. If you're trying to add the many-to-many field to the admin's "what `BakingPost`s am I looking at" controls, that's different. To do that, you should just be able to add category to your admin's [`list_filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) field, since in supports m2m fields by default.