# Cannot delete an item from the Django admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-admin

We used the Django admin interface to create some content (a 'Talk' model) and upload a file. The upload failed with a `Server Timeout Error (500)`.

Now, we cannot delete or even click on the talk in the admin interface. See screenshot:
[image: picture of the admin interface]

When we click on the item, we get a `Server Error (500)` message and Django outputs the following to our log files:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 850, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [non_field_errors] in None
DEBUG 2021-10-23 07:29:00,382 base 128 140297891723008 Exception while resolving variable 'non_field_errors' in template 'admin/change_list.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'non_field_errors'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'non_field_errors'
```

When we try to delete the item, we receive a slightly different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'non_field_errors'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 850, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [non_field_errors] in None
DEBUG 2021-10-23 07:21:19,130 base 128 140297916901120 Exception while resolving variable 'non_field_errors' in template 'admin/change_list.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

We are using Django version 2.1.15 with Python 3.8.

**Update**
As requested, the modeladmin for this model is:

```
class TalkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # The list display lets us control what is shown in the default talk table at Home > Website > Talk
    # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display
    list_display = ('title', 'date', 'get_speakers_as_csv', 'forum_name', 'location', 'talk_type')

    # search_fields are used for auto-complete, see:
    #   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields
    # for example, the PublicationAdmin uses auto-complete select2 for talks
    search_fields = ['title', 'forum_name']

    # Filters speakers only to current members and collaborators and sorts by first name
    # Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17457828
    # Update: we no longer do this because sometimes we want to add a talk by a former member or collaborator
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        print("TalkAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany: db_field: {} db_field.name {} request: {}".format(db_field, db_field.name, request))
        if db_field.name == "projects":
            kwargs["widget"] = widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple("projects", is_stacked=False)
        if db_field.name == "project_umbrellas":
            kwargs["widget"] = widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple("project umbrellas", is_stacked=False, )
        if db_field.name == "speakers":
            # Uncomment the following block of code to limit the speakers field in the admin UI only to current lab members
            # Note: we don't actually want to do this (see https://github.com/jonfroehlich/makeabilitylabwebsite/issues/534)
            # but keeping it here because code may be useful in the future for other areas of admin interface
            # current_member_and_collab_ids = [person.id for person in Person.objects.all() if person.is_current_member()]
            # filtered_speakers = Person.objects.filter(id__in=current_member_and_collab_ids).order_by('first_name')
            # kwargs["queryset"] = filtered_speakers
            kwargs["widget"] = widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple("speakers", is_stacked=False)
        if db_field.name == "keywords":
            kwargs["widget"] = widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple("keywords", is_stacked=False)
        return super(TalkAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Can you provide the modeladmin for this model?

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem. Updated original post with that code. You can see all of our admin models here: https://github.com/makeabilitylab/makeabilitylabwebsite/blob/master/website/admin.py